caret:: varImp() for caret::bagFDA() in R: Error in .(var) : could not find function "."
I am successfully running caret::bagFDA() in R, but I cannot use the caret::varImp() function to identify the most important variables.
The reproducible example is quite simple:
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(mda)
library(earth)

#GetData
data(iris)

#Run bagFDA
bagFDA_multivariate <- caret::bagFDA(as.factor(Species) ~ ., data = iris)

caret::varImp(bagFDA_multivariate)

The message I receive is:

Error in .(var) : could not find function "."

Can someone help me, please? Thanks! :)

Before using the function caret::varImp, it is necessary to load the plyr package.
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(mda)
library(earth)
library(plyr)

# GetData
data(iris)

# Run bagFDA
bagFDA_multivariate <- caret::bagFDA(as.factor(Species) ~ ., data = iris)

caret::varImp(bagFDA_multivariate)


              Overall
Petal.Length 73.347712
Petal.Width  63.057416
Sepal.Length 12.875676
Sepal.Width   7.849958

